# ToArray() vs new JArray() : which is more efficient to convert IEnumerable<T> to Collection<T>

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I need to convert the `IEnumerable<JToken>` result of a `LINQ` query to a Collection so I can use indexing on that. Now basically I found there are two ways to do so.

I can use the `ToArray()` to convert it to a `JToken[]`:

```
JToken[] arrElementValues = arrResults.Where(joResults => joResults["uResultId"]?.ToString() == arrTaskResults[intResult]["uResultId"]?.ToString() &&
                                       joResults["iElementId"]?.ToString() == strUniqueElementId && joResults["iContainerId"]?.ToString() == strContainerId).ToArray();
```

Or I can pass the `IEnumerable<JToken>` to a `JArray()`:

```
IEnumerable<JToken> enmElementValues = arrResults.Where(joResults => joResults["uResultId"]?.ToString() == arrTaskResults[intResult]["uResultId"]?.ToString() &&
                                       joResults["iElementId"]?.ToString() == strUniqueElementId && joResults["iContainerId"]?.ToString() == strContainerId);

JArray arrElementValues = new JArray(enmElementValues);
```

So which one is the better and efficient approach ?

Comment: Why don't you write a micro benchmark and see for yourself?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to find out whether or not there *is* a performance issue? It's unlikely to be a big one. Further, the meanings are different: One is an array of *tokens*, while the other is a representation of a JSON array. Use whichever suits your use-case best. [Further reading](https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/)

Comment: @Rob this is not a performance issue, both works fine as of now. Just wanted to know which is a better approach so that I can use the same approach throughout the project.

Comment: @izengod Well, unless you have a *need* for `JArray`, I'd say it makes more sense to stick with the regular .NET built in arrays.

Comment: When you add a pre-existing `JToken` to a `JArray`, if the `JToken` already has a [parent](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parent.htm), then the added token will actually get cloned.  If you want that, use `JArray`.  If you don't want that, use an array.  If you don't care, then choose whichever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do indexing on a list (`IReadOnlyList`). In your case the length of the input sequence is unknown so `ToArray` will use code similar to the code used in `ToList` to grow the buffer storing the enumerated items as the number of items increase. Initially the list will have a capacity of 4 items. When the 5th item is enumerated a new buffer will be created with twice the size and the original buffer will be copied to the new buffer (you cannot expand an already allocated array in .NET). This process continues until all items have been enumerated.

If the sequence has 10 items then the final buffer will have capacity for 16 items (4*2*2). Using `ToList` will return a list using this buffer but using `ToArray` will create a new array with 10 items and copy the buffer to the array shrinking the final storage so there is no excess capacity.

So using `ToList` compared to `ToArray` uses less CPU if the number of items doesn't match one of the capacities 4, 8, 16, 32, ... (the final allocation is skipped) but can use more memory (unused capacity in the buffer).

Using `JArray` adds additional semantics as noted in the comments and while it may perform just as well as `ToList` or perhaps `ToArray` it doesn't seem plausible that it contains some super fast algorithm for enumerating a sequence and storing the items in a memory buffer that is better than what `ToList` can do.

For small sequences using `ToList` or `ToArray` should not make any perceivable difference and if you really are having a performance problem you should measure it before you decide how to fix it.

Comment: Bingo! the answer I was looking for. thanks for your time and explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

A `JArray` is, logically, a representation of an array in a JSON structure.

A `JToken[]` is, logically, an array of JSON tokens.

Personally, I would prefer to call `ToArray` and have an array of JTokens, because I'm not actually constructing a JSON array here - I'm just collecting a bunch of JTokens in memory to process them. I would only use `JArray` if I wanted to construct - or deconstruct - an actual JSON structure. It's not a replacement for `JToken[]`.

Answer (score -3):

Go for Array, because it is fixed size structure in memory.

Comment: OP specifically says they want an array so they can index the elements, not an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: OP, go for the array then

Comment: @VijayRaheja that was the question, which conversion is better

Comment: Go for Array, because it is fixed size structure in memory.

Comment: @VijayRaheja: If that is your answer then you should edit your answer to reflect that. As it stands your answer doesn't seem to reflect what you are now saying in comments.